# How to reset CRM 2011 form data after an exception thrown in plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Folks,

Sometime  when a plugin is triggered and during execution an exception has occured, the CRM 2011 form which is going to be updated showing raw data in various fields. Some fields showing data before I modified them and some showing other but not the data that I have entered. Because after save()  the form reload, Is there any way to cancel the save() operation from whithin plugin or somehwere from JS  to avoid the form showing raw data.

Currently when this happens I compare the server side data with the client side data and reset the form again. Is there any other way around??

Answer (score 0):

When Plugin was thrown errr all of operations will be rollback. You just need to refresh your form（use F5 to refresh browser）.

Comment: Jeff, How would I refresh it from within the plugin?? OR Is there any way to receive it on the client side?